# "Missing context for method declaration" for overridden description method

Tags: objective-c

Am getting a "Missing context for method declaration" for my overridden description method. Can you tell what's wrong with the code?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRItem.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  @autoreleasepool {

      // Create a mutable array object, store its address in items variable
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    BNRItem *p = [[BNRItem alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %d", [p itemName], [p dateCreated], [p serialNumber], [p valueInDollars]);

    // This creates a new NSString, "Red Sofa" and gives it to the BNRItem
    [p setItemName:@"Red Sofa"];

    // This creates a new NSString, "A1B2C" and gives it to the BNRItem
    [p setSerialNumber:@"A1B2C"];

    // We send the value 100 to be used as the valueInDollars of this BNRItem
    [p setValueInDollars:100];

    // Destroy the array pointed to by items
    items = nil;

  }
    return 0;
}

-(NSString *)description // Missing context for method declaration
{
  NSString *descriptionString =
  [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@): Worth $%d, recorded on %@",
   itemName;
   serialNumber;
   valueInDollars;
   dateCreated];

return descriptionString;

}
```

BNRItem.m

```
#import "BNRItem.h"

@implementation BNRItem

-(void)setItemName:(NSString *)str {
  itemName = str;
}

-(NSString *)itemName {
  return itemName;
}

-(void)setSerialNumber:(NSString *)str {
  serialNumber = str;
}

-(NSString *)serialNumber {
  return serialNumber;
}

-(void)setValueInDollars:(int)i {
  valueInDollars = i;
}

-(int)valueInDollars {
  return valueInDollars;
}

-(NSDate *)dateCreated {
  return dateCreated;
}

-(NSString *)description
{
  NSString *descriptionString = 
  [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@): Worth $%d, recorded on %@",
   itemName,
   serialNumber; // Expected "]"
   valueInDollars, // Expression result unused
   dateCreated]; //Extraneous "]" before ";"

  return descriptionString;
}


@end
```

Comment: Thank you. I have moved the description method to BNRItem.m, but now have a different set of issues. Have pasted in BNRItem.m above.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Your method appears to be free floating inside `main.m`. An instance method needs to be placed inside the implementation section of a class. (between `@implementation` and `@end`).

My guess is that you should move that code into BNRItem.m.

Comment: Thank you. I have moved the description method to BNRItem.m, but now have a different set of issues. Have pasted in BNRItem.m above.

Comment: @pdenlinger: The errors are because you put a semicolon instead of a colon after `serialNumber`.

Comment: @jrturton: Yep. Too late to edit or I'd fix it. But I guess it worked out all right.

Comment: Doe! :) Sitting here thinking what's wrong with this! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If you have something like a char at the veryfirst beginning of your Header oder .m file, its also likely that this error accures.

```
^//
//  EMServices.m
//  MyController
//
//  Created by EMart on 09.01.14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 EMart. All rights reserved.
//
```